# How to know that the node of a specific type is being viewed for the first time?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to display a block on the node page if it is being viewed for the first time. After that that block will not be displaying.

It will be for all the nodes of a given content type.

I know the Drupal put the node in the cache if it is being viewed for the first time but I can't found its code.

Is it possible? Any Ideas?

Comment: Viewed by some specific user or all user ?

Comment: all users and the block will be a custom block.

Comment: update question with  more details clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the core statistics module.

and then on node view used the function [statistics_get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.module/function/statistics_get/7) function and then check it the total count is less than 1.

Comment: Great! it's so useful

Answer (score 0):

Use Views Blocks and filter it with *Content: Has new content* to know if it is being viewed for the first time.

Comment: if also contains if a node is being updated. and also I have to display a custom block.